# Adding AJAX to a working PHP form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a working PHP registration form that goes through `$_POST[]` requests to check user inputs.

- Username length (3-20)
- Username availability
- Username /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/
- etc.

Rather than have it take you to a whole new page to display errors, I want a live request to call for the errors from register.php so they will appear in a div on the registration.

```
<div id="errors">" . $usernameErrors . "</div>
```

I've been trying to read up on AJAX but have noticed most codes involve utilizing $_GET[].
What will I have to do to get my current forms integrated with AJAX?

My Current Basic Registration Form *Logic*:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required />
    $usernameErrors
</form>
```

And register.php contains all of the checks already.

Comment: Why not just validate that stuff through Javascript locally, instead of calling a remote script? You would still have to validate it remotely, but only when the user submits the form. Telling the user his/her errors in real-time is just for their convenience, so Javascript will work fine here.

Comment: @LoganSerman thats what I thought. But it also checks for username availability.

Comment: Are you checking the errors as each box is filled, or at the click of a button? If it's at the click of a button, I see no difference between a regular post/AJAX, especially if the registration process will take you to another page. It'll also save you having to post to another page, when everything can be done on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it's pretty simple.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $.post('/register.php', 
           {username: $('#username').val()
            // insert values of other fields here
           }, 
           function(response) {
               // update your div with errors
               $('#errors').html(response);
           })

</script>
```

You should invoke this code, for example, when user changes username in registration form. It will happen in background and update page asynchronously.

Your register.php script should, in this case, emit only errors, not the whole page, or you will see unexpected results. :-)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp can give more reading if Sergei's example isn't enough.

Comment: @JClaspill never ever again use w3schools as a reference please!

Comment: @PeeHaa Why is that? (also curious)

Comment: Coding is learning. Any page that has valid code is a reference. I didn't say read their site on php, or read their site on css. I pointed to a specific page that has a valid example and explanation of such below it. Personally, I'd use the $.ajax over $.post anyway.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev w3school is full of errors / flaws / bad practice etc. Basically no one should ever look at it :0

Comment: @PeeHaa: it was useful to me at times. Though I prefer official documentation if there is one.

Comment: I don't like w3 schools either, but honestly the very large majority of their examples are just fine. They're bad for not fixing their mistakes, but they remain an effective resource.

Answer (score 2):

In order to simplify ajax, you can use jQuery (a very powerful JS lib).
Add jquery***.js to your project and refer it on your page:

```
 << script type="text/javascript" src="#js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" />
```

Then, you create the javascript function that will make the ajax call. 
On the ajax call, you specify the php file to call and the function to handle the return of php(callback). On this callback function, you add the error message to body.

```
function verifyForm(){
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "register.php",
   data: "username=NAME_GOT_FROM_FORM_&location=Boston"
 }).done(function( returned ) { //the callback
   $('#errors').html(returned); // add the string returned to div id=errors
 });
}
```

Comment: Sergei's answer wasn't available when I started to answer. We recommended the same thing. I'll only keep my one because it can complement Sergei's one.

Also useful: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

So, the crux of the problem as you're asking it seems to be that you're (correctly) using a POST request on your register form, but your tutorials all want to use GET. Here's a discussion about the difference between the two methods:

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post/

If you're actually registering the user with AJAX (rather than just validating) you should be submitting the AJAX request as a POST. If you're using jQuery, the answer has already been given. If you're not using jQuery, then look for the XMLHttpRequest object in your tutorial, and where its "open" method is called (reference here: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/). The first parameter of that function is a request method--change it to "post" rather than "get", and the request will be treated like a POST, which register.php expects.

That being said, it sounds like you just want AJAX to *validate* the form. In that case, GET is the correct verb to use--all you want to do with AJAX is check data against the database, not actually make a change to data. I would suggest that you actually write a new PHP script like validate_registration.php that will perform only the validation logic in register.php, and then return a JSON array of errors (which would be empty if no errors occurred). You can activate/deactivate your form submit button based on that return value, and let the user submit the form just like your old workflow if everything is okay.

The tl;dr here is that you should read up on what makes $_GET and $_POST different, and then write an AJAX-specific validation script so that you're separating the data-retrieval part of your process from the data-insertion part. Once you understand the difference, the rest should follow.